# ajax:before clearing input

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form.

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@something, :remote => true ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :label => false, :placeholder => "Add new something" %>
  <% end %>
```

It has no button, the submission is achieved through hitting return.

There's some javascript to act on the submission of the form.

```
$('form.new_something')
  .on("ajax:before", function(){
    $text_box = $('input:text', this);
    $text_box.prop('disabled', true);
    $text_box.val('Loading...');
  })
```

This results in 'name' property of my my new Something model **being set to 'null'** instead of the value of the text box.

I presume this is because I'm using "ajax:before" which is triggered just before the post is made.

Any advice on what I should do?

Comment: Why do you set `$text_box.prop('disabled', true);` using `.prop()`  and not `.attr()` when [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) is an [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and not a [property](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) ?

Comment: jQuery advise using prop -  http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2

Comment: Yeah right! I guess it does. I hope this is equivalent to `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')`, doesn't makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `.on('submit', function(){...})`?